# NSwag - Generate code not compiling because of duplicate property but different types. What does it mean?

Tags: c#, api, nswag

I get an error on the following code:

```
    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("@id", Required = Newtonsoft.Json.Required.DisallowNull, NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("id", Required = Newtonsoft.Json.Required.DisallowNull, NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
```

I do understand the error which is:
"Already contains a definition for id"
But 2 questions,

1. What does the @ do in the first id(string)
2. How to fix it?

This is what was generated by NSwag, I have no access or control of the api which NSwag used to generate the code.

Comment: Can you share your Swagger specificatin? My guess is that there are two properties, one called `id` and one called `@id`, and NSwag is doing bad code generation from that

Comment: Also tell us what command line parameters, or other place you set parameters, you gave for nSwag - there are things you can do accidentally when e.g configuring whether you want single or multiple clients that will end up causing name collisions in the generated code. If you can share the swagger spec also, it would help